# How to get the equivalent index of each case in 2 python lists

Tags: python

I am trying to get the value of 2 python lists.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list1 = ['1','2','3']
```

the output

```
['a','1']
['b','2']
['c','3']
```

I am still beginner with python

Any help will be apperciate

Comment: Looking into the [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) function would be a start.

Comment: `[[x, y] for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: try this [list(a) for a in zip(list1, list2)]

Comment: I think @AndyG 's comment is a good pointer for the OP to start formulating a solution. I don't understand why answers are being posted. Some time should be allotted for the OP to look into the concept of zip. If the OP is unable to come up with a solution, he / she will edit the question / comment asking for more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` for generic usage:

```
map(lambda *x: list(x), list1, list2)
[['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

or `zip` within a list comprehension:

```
[list(v) for v in zip(list1, list2)]
[['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
```

both of them can be easily expanded for more lists:

```
list3 = ["9", "8", "7"]

map(lambda *x: list(x), list1, list2, list3)
[['a', '1', '9'], ['b', '2', '8'], ['c', '3', '7']]

[list(v) for v in zip(list1, list2, list3)]
[['a', '1', '9'], ['b', '2', '8'], ['c', '3', '7']]
```

Comment: i try the zip function its work fine for me thans Andy G , RoadRunner and Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zip builtin to generate tuples containing an element for each corresponding position from each list

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['1','2','3']
for tuple in (zip(list1, list2)):
    # Cast each tuple to a list and print it
    print(list(tuple))
>>['a', '1']
>>['b', '2']
>>['c', '3']
```